# Exclusive access to a PostgreSQL table through python or Postgres

Tags: python, postgresql

I have a table with a list of URL in stored in PG and I have an application which is supposed to take a subset of available URLs and process them. This application will update the processed field=true when it retrieves the set of URLs. I am going to have multiple instances running on different machines. How do I ensure my access to PG is exclusive, so I don't end up with same set of URLs on different machines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can lock rows in multiple ways, in postgresql: table-level locks, row-level locks, and advisory locks.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/explicit-locking.html

In your case, however, locking is not going to be enough if you want good concurrency:

```
update links
set processing = true
where id in (
  select id
  from links
  where not processed
  and not processing
  limit 100
  for update
  )
returning *
```

The extra `processing` field makes it possible to have multiple jobs to work on different sets of rows.

Answer (score 2):

This problem can be solved purely in your postgresql queries using the `LOCK` statement.  Here is a link to the documentation with examples:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-lock.html